# Changing UITabbar when the app theme is being changed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to support 2 themes for an app. Light and Dark one. So, I have a `UIButton` that allows the user to tap on it and switch between light and dark theme.

The `UITabBar` has it's own class and I've set it to change accordingly to the current theme but it's not working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class MainTabbar: UITabBarController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = Theme.current.tabbarTintColor
        self.tabBar.tintColor = Theme.current.tabbarSelectedItems
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = Theme.current.tabbarUnselectedItemsColor
    }
}
```

In the `AppDelegate` file, I check whether there's a selected theme if not, set the `LightTheme`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
 // Set Theme
 if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: SelectedThemeKey) != nil {
        Theme.current = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: SelectedThemeKey) ? LightTheme() : DarkTheme()
        print("current theme is: \(Theme.current)")
    }
 }
```

As of now, it only changes the colors of the `UITabbar` IF the app is being relaunched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the app theme is changed you need to access these anywhere either inside any tab

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barTintColor = Theme.current.tabbarTintColor
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = Theme.current.tabbarSelectedItems
self.tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = Theme.current.tabbarUnselectedItemsColor
```

//

Or if the root is the tabController

```
let tab = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
```

Comment: Damn, I thought I can change it in a single file only. I certainly cannot set it as a root view controller in `AppDelegate` because it's not a `rootViewController`

Comment: anywhere you change the Theme if the tabBarController is presented  access it and change the properties as **viewWillAppear** is called when there is another VC above the tabBar poped , it works after relaunch as viewWillAppear is called again for sure